# Laravel Eloquent ORM: Select from two tables without using find() possible?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Basically I would like to run a very simple database select query accross two tables in mysql considering a one-to-many-relationship.

**categories**: This table contains all product-categories. **The primary key is "id"**. It has one column "url" which holds the string how to access this category, e.g. "greeting-cards".

**products**: This table contains all products whereas each product has one category id. **The primary key is "id".** It has one column "category_id" which represents the id of the category the product corresponds to.

So, according to the documentation of Eloquent ORM, I did this:

`$products = \App\Category::find($CATEGORY_ID)->products);`

And it's is working like a charm.

Now the problem is:
When accessing a webpage, the URL doesn't look like this:

`www.domain.tld/categories/123`

However, it looks like this due to SEO:

`www.domain.tld/categories/greeting-cards`

Therefore, I modified the database query like  this:

`$products = \App\Category::where('url', $category)->products);`

But this does not work!
Do I see it correctly that I **have** to use find() and placing a where() method is wrong here? Are there any other approaches to do this in Eloquent? I don't like to use a second database query to get the ID of the corresponding category url and then paste this id into the database query... I know this is possible, but I think there should be more elegant ways to this in Eloquent?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `$products = \App\Category::where('url', $category)->first()->products;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to retrieve the model in order to use its relations.

If you want to use `where()` just call [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models):

Example:

```
\App\Category::where('url', $category)->first()->products
```

More methods are available at Laravel's docs: [Retrieveing single models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

Comment: Keep in mind that the result of `Category::where('url', $category)->first()` can be null if there was no match, which will yield an error of trying to access properties of a non-object.

Comment: thank you guys for your help! That was the trick! By the way, just out of interest: How will the SQL query look like when running ```\App\Category::where('url', $category)->first()->products?``` Will this be one query (by using ```WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id```) or two in total?